# kafka topic need to disable for few days

Tags: apache-kafka

we are using kafka 0.10.x, I have a requirement of disabling the kafka topic for few days. I do not want to **delete the topic**  but just to **put it in offline mode**. Is there a way we have to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is no. But you can use [Apache Sentry](https://sentry.apache.org/) and set a access to a Kafka topic.

You can see more information here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SENTRY/Apache+Kafka+Authorization+with+Apache+Sentry